# how to count down the trail time of an android application

Tags: android

I would like to count down the time of trial version of the android application.

**Code:**

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime local= dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
String str = fmt.print(local);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The time is "+str ,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

here i got the current time of app. I want to get this at the time of the installation and after getting the current time at the time of installation have to fix a date exactly after 30 days from the time of installation. How can i procceed using the joda time library?

**How to start the current time when the installation is done.**

Comment: user may misuse it as app can be reused multiple times by uninstalling  and reinstalling.

Comment: Ok no problem, i just want to check how many persons are updating the application regularly and reinstalling doesnt matter here.

Answer (score 0):

use installation time from app directly:

```
long installed = context
    .getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo("package.name", 0)
    .firstInstallTime
;
```

Comment: sorry i cant get what you are saying !!! my concern is that i want to install the time when the installation is done !!!

Comment: from above method in your application you can retrieve the installation time of your application, code this in your application.